# How can I finish the compareTo(Object o) method here?

Tags: java

This is the abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractRecord {
    /**
     * Simple getter for the similarity 
     * 
     * @return <code>int</code> containing the similarity
     */
    public abstract int getSimilarity();

    /**
     * Simple getter for the title <code>String</code>
     * 
     * @return <code>String</code> containing the title
     */
    public abstract String getTitle();

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "["+this.title+":"+this.similarity+ "]";
    }
}
```

and this is the extended class from it:

```
public class Record extends AbstractRecord implements Comparable<Record>{
    private int similarity;
    private String title;

    public Record(String title, int similarity) throws IndexException {
        if (title == null || title.isEmpty() || similarity < 0) {
            throw new IndexException("Missing title");
        }
        this.similarity = similarity;
        this.title = title;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Record r) {
        int result;
        result = r.compareTo( //what should I put here? );
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSimilarity() {
        return similarity;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

}
```

Just fixed super variable problem and here's a new problem..
How can I fixed the compareTo() method here, trying to compare the input Record r with the local one.
Thank you!

Comment: Just don't declare it in the subclass. You can access the variables of the base class directly.

Comment: Btw.: Why do you declare the two fields in the base class when you don't implement their getter there?

Comment: Make the `getter` `abstract` then all will become clear.

Comment: Convince yourself with a debugger that if you did add the variable in the subclass it would not "overwri[te]" the super's.

Answer (score 5):

```
 private int similarity;
 private String title;
```

No need to declare title and similarity in subclass you can initialize it using super keyword

Comment: How can I retrieve the value from super class?

Comment: @Ryan as both fields are `protected`, they will be automatically inherited by the subclasses. So you can simple use them as if they were declared on subclass level. (`this.similarity`)

Answer (score 2):

Your `title` and `similarity` members of the Record class hide the members of the same name of `AbstractRecord`.

If all `AbstractRecord`s have a `title` and `similarity`, it would make more sense to implement `getTitle()` and `getSimilarity()` in `AbstractRecord`, instead of in `Record`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your fields of abstract class `protected` or `public`. And for security and access permission's sake, `protected` is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

your variables are automatically inherited. There is no need to declare it in the subclass. It is not going to override the superclass variable

```
public class Record extends AbstractRecord implements Comparable<Record>{
    //your methods here
}
```

Above code should suffice

Answer (score 0):

Both the fields of base class will be inherited to child class. You simply need to use `super` keyword to access fields of Base class as:

`super.similarity` and `super.title`

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to initialize the parent class(**AbstractRecord**) variable
it can by done in parent class constructor or in child class by **super** keyword

```
super.title = "value";
```

This same keyword you can use to access it too.

```
public String getParentTitle(){
     return super.title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not redefined the `title` and `similarity` attributes in the subclass, and making `abstract` getters in the class where the actual attributes are defined seems over-complicated. Then as a rule of thumb, attributes in a class should be initialise in the class.

Sub-classes inherits all `public` and `protected` members (methods and attributes). It means you can use them without having to redeclare it.

In the below simplified version of your code, I kept parameter checking in the subclass constructor, assuming you can have different subclasses with different constraints. Note that if the comparison of records is only on `title` and `similarity`, you can implement it in `AbstractRecord`.

```
public abstract class AbstractRecord {
    protected String title;
    protected int similarity;

    protected AbstractRecord(String title, int similarity) {
        this.title = title;
        this.similarity = similarity;
    }

    public  int getSimilarity() {return similarity;}

    public  String getTitle() {return title;}

    public String toString() {
        return "["+this.title+":"+this.similarity+ "]";
    }

    // some abstract methods
}

public class Record extends AbstractRecord implements Comparable<Record>{

    public Record(String title, int similarity) throws IndexException {
        super(title, similarity);
        if (title == null || title.isEmpty() || similarity < 0) {
            throw new IndexException("Missing title");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Record r) {
        return 0;
    }
    // implementation of abstract methods from AbstractRecord 
}
```